# Using Tailwind dark variant with custom classes

Tags: tailwind-css

Does tailwind allow the `dark` variant to work with custom classes?

Consider this simple working example:

```
<div class="bg-white dark:bg-black">
    Hello, world
</div>
```

The above will apply a black background to the element, but if try to use a custom class, then it won't:

```
`style.css`
.card-background {
    @apply bg-black;
}

`index.html`
<div class="bg-white dark:card-background">
    Hello, world
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two way,

- if you want to work just with colors, you can insert your colors into tailwind config file
- if not you must define the dark class for every custom classes that you need.

for example

```
 .dark {
   .dark\:card-background {
     @apply bg-black;
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with `cssModules`, and especially with `css-loader`.

Solution described here
https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/issues/3258#issuecomment-753584532

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/997587